Did the healing power source from Jesus or from the Holy Spirit?
Jesus taught that blasphemy against the Holy Spirit will not be forgiven after the Pharisees and Sadducees claimed he was using the power of Beelzebub-the prince of demons to heal. In this response, Jesus is not only acknowledging that the power to heal sources from a distinct entity called the Holy Ghost but also distinguishes himself from the later by acknowledging that he is not that entity but the son of man.
Mathew 12:31

He who is not with Me is against Me, and he who does not gather with Me scatters. 31Therefore I tell you, every sin and blasphemy will be forgiven men, but the blasphemy against the Spirit will not be forgiven. 32Whoever speaks a word against the Son of Man will be forgiven, but whoever speaks against the Holy Spirit will not be forgiven, either in this age or in the one to come.

Does the statement above show the healing power sourced from the Holy Spirit?

That text, in itself, does not 'prove' your thesis one way or the other. You need other textual evidence to come to conclusions.

@NigelJ, yes it does because Jesus is saying that the pharisees have blasphemed the Holy Ghost by claiming that my healing power comes from Beelzebub the chief of demons, that is the exact meaning of his response.

But it does not 'prove' that the origin of power is also himself, as One with that Spirit and as One with the Father.

@NigelJ, the three share a united divine will so Jesus here told us indirectly where the power was sourcing from, and those that blasphemed the Holy Ghost will not be forgiven in this age or in the age to come.

The answer obviously depends on our understanding of who Jesus is and what is His nature.  From the Chalcedonian perspective, there is no "distinct entity called the Holy Ghost" since Jesus and God IS one Being.  In Matt 12:31 Jesus distinguishes his human nature ("son of man") from his divine nature (shared by the Holy Ghost).  In verses where Jesus says his father is greater than he, he refers to his divine nature is greater than his human nature.
Since there is only one Being, it is very easy to conceive that the healing power is sourced from his own Being as at that time Jesus is operating in his divine nature.  This is an example where once we conceive Jesus in Chalcedonian terms, everything in the gospels makes sense.

If The Holy Ghost is the Father as you claim, why did Jesus use the phrase Father to refer to him who is on the Great White Throne and Holy Ghost to refer to the helper? Jesus would never confuse his listeners unless those two beings are different. I and the Father are One then he Jesus switches terms all of a sudden and refers to Him as the Holy Spirit?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany I think you should look about the site for questions on the Holy Trinity. You could start with my answer to this question on modalism. You are not making the proper Trinitarian distinctions between person and nature.

@jaredad7, those are personal interpretations, I also have my own direct interpretation from the Bible and there is no way Jesus would switch all of a sudden from referring to God as the Father to the Holy Spirit unless they are different.

The Father and the Holy Spirit are different.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany This answer does not say that the Holy Spirit is the Father.
